# Blazor Client side RemoteAuthenticatorView

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-client-side

What is the purpose of RemoteAuthenticatorView in Blazor Client side? It seems to redirect to an identity server, but cant we do that directly by creating simple links inside the app that go to the corresponding pages in the Identity Server? Does it serve any additional purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Well, ,i just figured out that using direck links on hrefs doens't append jwt token to the header thus failing any possible security check.